# How to show only an image of the YouTube video while using Media: YouTube module?

Tags: 7, media, files, nodes

Is there a way to show an image of a youtube video instead of the actual player ? This would be done only for the teaser view of the node.

I know that I can show a video thumbnail, but I need an image that looks like the actual player.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you can grab the id of youtube video then you can use following pattern of url to get  a bigger youtube thumbnail.

`http://img.youtube.com/vi/[your video id]/0.jpg`

Answer (score 2):

This would require a little work on your behalf to write a small module to get the youtube thumbnail and then process it.

For example if you use [Embedded Media Field](http://drupal.org/project/emfield) with [Media: Youtube](http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube) then you can get the URL with `$node->field_emvideo[0]['data']['thumbnail']['url']` (*field_emvideo* is the name of your field) and use it with [ImageCache Actions](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) to add a background image which would be the Youtube player.

I don't have a full code to offer but using [ImageCache API](http://drupal.org/node/163561) (see the code snippet at the bottom) is quite simple, ex:

```
<?php
 print theme('imagecache', $preset, $image['filepath'], $alt, $title,  $attributes); 
?>
```

Good luck ;)